# Software to organize my ebook readings

Tags: ebook

I´m looking for a software that let me organize my readings of ebooks. Not only to organize my ebook collection, but also to keep track the book, pages or chapters in wich i am.
 I  read a lot of books at once (academics, entertainment, etc.), and I wonder if something as simple as a bookmark is available for ebooks. I can take a note in notepad, but is this all?

To be clear enough: I get my laptop, and I say: "ok, In what was I?" It can be a poem in the middle of a compilation, a chapter in a technical book, or the last issue of a electronic magazine. I want to open this program and see: "I´m in the third chapter of this book".

Answer (score 4):

I use Calibre for my ebook management. It supports many different devices and can automatically convert to the best format for your reader.

Link: http://calibre-ebook.com/

Comment: +1 Calibre is **awesome** software.  It's also free/open source.